# showing cluster in calendar

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I am doing a hierarchical cluster analysis.

The final data looks like: chr, int, int,..., clustergroup.

The first column (chr) are dates, which are not included in the clusteranalysis.

Is there a way to show the clusters on a calendar? I have column for date and a column for cluster.

What I have already:

```
data$dayNumber <-  yday(data$Date)
calendR(year = 2020, start = "M", special.days ="weekend")
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I have found an answer:

```
calendar <- 1:365
calendar [1:365] <- rep(NA)
final_data$yday <- yday(final_data$Date)
final_data$clusterNames <- paste("Cluster ", final_data$cluster)
calendar[final_data$yday] <- final_data$clusterNames

calendR(year = 2020, start = "M", special.days =calendar, 
special.col = c("pink", "lightblue","lightgreen"), legend.pos = "right")
```

Answer (score 0):

Hierarchical techniques are found at the distance matrix. The basic function in R is:

```
dist(x, method = "euclidean", diag = FALSE, upper = FALSE, p = 2)
dist(nameofdtaset)
```

The methods available in this function are: "euclidean", "maximum", "manhattan", "canberra", "binary", "minkowski".
But there are other functions for calculating distances.

I don't think that with R You can show the clusters on a calendar, but if you need you can use some graph to make it similar